# mysqldump command with java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) not generating dump

Tags: java, runtime, exec, mysql

i have tried with the following code snippet:

```
Process p;

String command="mysqldump -u'scmuser' -p'scm$123' --routines db_name  >  /home/ubuntu/wh_demo_db_reset.sql";
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

the dump file is not generated and not thrown any error. i am unable to predict the exact issue please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metacharacter ">" is implemented by the shell; no shell is involved in running a program with Runtime.exec() so the last two arguments to mysqldump are garbage. Use the array argument form of Runtime.exec(); pass "/bin/sh" as the first argument, "-c" as the second, and your command line as the third; that way the shell metacharacters will be interpreted by /bin/sh.

You can form the cmd array as:

```
String[] cmdarray = {"/bin/sh","-c",command}; 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
```

Comment: Thanks ..abhijeet i am working on that ...does it work on windows machine? if not how to make it work on windows also.

Comment: You will need to use following command format for windows: 

     String[] command = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:/path/to/mysqldump.exe")+" --quick --lock-tables --user=myuser --password=mypwd mydatabase"};
      final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

But you will not be able to redirect the output of command to the file as what we do in linux using '>' operator. 
You can do that using BufferedReader/Writer.

Comment: Thanks..abhijeet..but it is generating dump file of 0 size.